# Add shape over powerpoint chart in c# VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

**Im trying to add shape over powerpoint chart in VSTO.**

```
chart.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 50, 50, 100f, 100f);
```

this code throws exception: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

I guess im doing something wrong here, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working after spending much time on it. In the end it was quite simple.
**Successfully Added a shape over chart using this code.**

```
       var Button = Chart.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeActionButtonCustom, float.Parse((Chart.ChartArea.Left + 5).ToString()), float.Parse((Chart.ChartArea.Top + Chart.ChartArea.Height).ToString()), 33, 34);
       Button.Name = "Sample Button";
       Button.Fill.UserPicture(@"C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\ChartIcon.PNG");
```